# guid generator in ruby

Tags: ruby, guid, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guids in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117584/guids-in-ruby)

How do I generate a globally unique ID in ruby (without rails/merb)?