# Rails 3: Generate unique codes (coupons)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best way to generate unique codes to use as coupon codes?

Thanks.

Comment: Name them? I mean, some human has to concieve of the coupon and what it does. Have them provide a name. Just make sure the name hasn't been used before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating unique, hard-to-guess "coupon" codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333237/generating-unique-hard-to-guess-coupon-codes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this too:

```
chars = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
def String.random_alphanumeric(size=16)
    (0...size).collect { chars[Kernel.rand(chars.length)] }.join
end
```

But then you would have to compare against a database to make sure it is not used yet.

Comment: Question asks for Ruby/Rails solution.

Comment: realized and changed - i got confused between questions

Comment: It still doesn't look like ruby ;)

Comment: replace first line with `chars = ('A'..'Z').to_a`.  if you want numbers and uppercase do `chars = (0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a`

Comment: You should use `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` for this rather than coding your own functionality.

Answer (score 39):

In Ruby's standard library there is `SecureRandom` for this:

```
SecureRandom.hex(3)
```

The length of the output is double of what the length input specified.

Comment: +1 for having security in mind.  A user being able to guess or generate valid coupon codes could be anywhere from annoying to really bad.  The OP needs to be concerned not just with the cryptographic strength of the random number generator, but with the ratio between the size of the "key space" and the number of coupons that will potentially be issued.  The lower that ratio, the more likely someone will be able to guess a coupon code at random.

Comment: Removed as of rails 3.2 - use simply SecureRandom from stdlib. see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1087

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is to generate a GUID.  See here:

[guid generator in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522915/guid-generator-in-ruby)

Comment: @codethis: what I want is more of coupon codes like groupon has.

Comment: When you buy something from groupon, you get a code to redeem the service. It's basically random numbers and letters I believe but no two codes can be the same.

Comment: It can be as much as needed. Not defined yet.

Comment: so that is what a GUID is - just get rid of the `-`'s from the generated string

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try this, seems to be more proof than just generating some random key.
They say: UUID generator for producing universally unique identifiers based on RFC 4122 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). 
http://rubygems.org/gems/uuid

```
gem install uuid
cd /myproject/path
uuid-setup
```

In your code

```
require_gem 'uuid'
my_unique_id_var = UUID.new
```

Reference: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=12616#p44545

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to waste comparing against the database (not a super expensive operation), you can guarantee that Time is always unique because it only occurs once

```
md5(Time.now.to_i.to_s+Time.now.usec.to_s)
```

Comment: I like this one, although SHA2 would be even more secure (but slower).

Comment: Unless you pair this with the user's name or id you'd run the risk of race conditions - two processes generating the same time/coupon code for different users. It'd be rare but possible and very hard to debug. Try `md5(current_user.id.to_s + Time.now.to_i.to_s+Time.now.usec.to_s)` instead.

Comment: Time is not unique. See Daylight Savings Time; you get a whole hour worth of repeated time once a year. And then there's the matter of being able to change the system clock. Use a GUID/UIID

Answer (score 2):

Note: There is [a same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333237/generating-unique-hard-to-guess-coupon-codes/27596897#27596897)

Recently I wrote [coupon-code gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/coupon_code) that does exactly the same thing. The algorithm borrowed from Algorithm::CouponCode CPAN module.

A coupon code should not only be unique, but also easy to read and type while it still is secure. Neil's explanation and solution is great. This gem provides a convenient way to do it and a bonus validation feature.

```ruby
>> require 'coupon_code'
>> code = CouponCode.generate
=> "1K7Q-CTFM-LMTC"
>> CouponCode.validate(code)
=> "1K7Q-CTFM-LMTC"
>> CouponCode.validate('1K7Q-CTFM-LMTO') # Invalid code
=> nil
```