# How do I move my ruby iteration into my controller / model in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a basic username / password generator which creates X random usernames and passwords. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558250/rails-3-generate-unique-codes-coupons) post as the basis. It works ok in the console but I do not understand how to get it to work properly in my RoR3.1 application.

I need to create a simple form which I can input the following variables:

1. Number of iterations (X) required
2. Length of username (Y)
3. Length of password (Z)

Then, when I click save, I need the application to create X usernames and password and save to the db.

I have managed to get it working by calling the action upon page load, but I do not know how to create a form which will pass over the variables.

I've created this in my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  private

  def self.generate_batch
    10.times do
     username = ""
     password =""
     5.times { username << (i = Kernel.rand(62); i += ((i < 10) ? 48 : ((i < 36) ? 55 : 61 ))).chr }
     5.times { password << (i = Kernel.rand(62); i += ((i < 10) ? 48 : ((i < 36) ? 55 : 61 ))).chr }
     User.create!(:username => username, :check_attributes => [ {:attribute_name => "User-Password", :value => password, :op => ":="}])
    end
  end      
end
```

In my users controller, I created a new action:

```
def new_batch
  @user = User.new
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save      
      @user = User.generate_batch
    else
      format.html { render action: "new_batch" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And in my routes:

```
get "/batch" => "users#new_batch"
```

I started with a blank form to see if I could at least get it going with the variables hardcoded:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.submit
```

When I hit submit, it looks like it tries to use my create action, instead of generating the batch...

What do I need to do to:

1. Get the form to submit properly
2. Enter the variables as above

Thanks in advance

-- UPDATE --

Following the advice below, I've created two controllers:

routes.rb now has this:

```
  get "/batch" => 'users#new_batch'
  put "/batch" => 'users#new_batch_create'
```

And the controller like this:

```
  def new_batch
  end

  def new_batch_create
     @user = User.generate_batch 
  end
```

Now, when I hit submit, it processes through loop :)

Still don't quite understand how to pass the variables over from the form...

Comment: The logic of your controller is off. You need to seperate the generation of the form for create and the processing of that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 2 controllers. One to call to get the form and one to post/get your action.
This is the same as with your regular controllers, New/Edit and Create/Update.

If you have a object in your views used to create the fields, use the below form

```
= form_for(@user, :method => :put, :url => url_for({:controller => :users, :action => :new_batch)) do |f|
  = f.submit 'Submit', {:class => 'btn'}
```

otherwise just create your own form with `_tag` helpers

```
= form_tag("/batch"", :method => :get) do |f|
  = submit_tag 'Submit', {:class => 'btn'}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. How do I go about sending the variables over to loop? S

Comment: Can't seem to get this working, think there's something wrong with my routes. Any chance you could have a look? Have updated my question S

Comment: Ok, managed to figure it out. Still not sure about passing the variables over though?

Comment: you can simply add them in your form. They will be appended to the url for a get and appended to the header for a post. I suggest you have a look at the standard pages rails generates if you scaffold your models.