# Integrate referrel and promo codes in rails applicaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a feature requirement to integrate referrel and promo codes in rails application. Please suggest the best way to implement it.

Comment: for promo code see this gem : https://github.com/baxang/coupon-code

Comment: I prefer to create promo codes without using any gem. Please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333237/generating-unique-hard-to-guess-coupon-codes

Comment: Another gem: https://github.com/fnando/coupons. Please always remember to Google first before asking a question on Stack Overflow. Thank you

Comment: My first motive is to ask about referrel program.