# How to generate a 16-digit robust not guessable coupon code?

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a robust ruby code to create 16 digit not guessable coupon codes.

I.e. AH9A-TE9A-443G-TGRW

There is a promising pseudocode at [this answer written by Neil Slater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333237/generating-unique-hard-to-guess-coupon-codes/22333563?noredirect=1#comment137900188_22333563)

```rb
# Random, unguessable number as a base20 string
#  .rjust(12, '0') covers for unlikely, but possible small numbers
#  .reverse ensures we don't use first character (which may not take all values)
raw = SecureRandom.random_number( 2**80 ).to_s( 20 ).rjust(12, '0').reverse
# e.g. "3ecg4f2f3d2ei0236gi"


# Convert Ruby base 20 to better characters for user experience
long_code = raw.tr( '0123456789abcdefghij', '234679QWERTYUPADFGHX' )
# e.g. "6AUF7D4D6P4AH246QFH"


# Format the code for printing
short_code = long_code[0..3] + '-' + long_code[4..7] + '-' + long_code[8..11]
# e.g. "6AUF-7D4D-6P4A"
```

Now I need help to turn this pseudo-code into watertight code for my use-case. I cannot and do not want to use ruby gem to create the codes.

Comment: Looks like this code is pretty functional as it is. You just have to change it to output groups of 4 characters instead of 3.

Comment: What’s wrong with the given code? Why doesn’t it work for you?

Comment: It works great, I wasn't sure if it was a good idea to use it productively. It seems like there are even simpler solutions with Ruby now. But the code is great. @Neil Slater has in-depth knowledge and understanding here.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
require 'securerandom'

4.times.map { SecureRandom.alphanumeric(4) }.join('-')
#=> "HyaT-PDMa-IFMn-Ra6o"
```

If you want to use a specific alphabet:

```
ALPHABET = '234679QWERTYUPADFGHX'.split(//)

4.times.map { SecureRandom.send(:choose, ALPHABET, 4) }.join('-')
#=> "GQPG-QXEH-QFRA-9XPF"
```

And when you are using Ruby on Rails you might want to consider the [`base58` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/SecureRandom.html#method-c-base58) that excludes some characters that are easy to be mistaken like `["0", "O", "I", "l"]`:

```
4.times.map { SecureRandom.base58(4) }.join('-')
#=> "pEho-gpHk-sHDc-5BF6"
```

Comment: `'234679QWERTYUPADFGHX'.to_a` does not work. Instead, `'234679QWERTYUPADFGHX'.split('')`. `SecureRandom.send(:choose, ALPHABET, 4)` is making use of a private method, [Random::Formatter](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/Random/Formatter.html) does not yet seem to be fully baked. [3.4 will add the option to pass a character set into `alphanumeric`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-alphanumeric).

Comment: [Rails has a compatibility method to apply its own character set prior to Ruby 3.3](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6f0d1ad14b92b9f5906e44740fce8b4f1c7075dc/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/securerandom.rb#L24), it's a few lines and the method can be copied into an application.

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby master (what *may* become 3.4) introduces a more robust formatting interface for SecureRandom](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Random/Formatter.html). It's present in Ruby 3.3, but it does not appear to be fully baked. [SecureRandom in 3.3.0](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/stdlibs/securerandom/SecureRandom.html) claims to have a bunch of Random::Formatter methods which [Random::Formatter](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/Random/Formatter.html) does not document. There is no guarantee it will continue to work in 3.3.x nor that 3.4 will work as currently documented in master. Use at your own risk. Unit test it to catch a breaking change quickly.

That new method makes this very simple...

```
COUPON_CHARS = '234679QWERTYUPADFGHX'.split(//)
SecureRandom.alphanumeric(4, chars: COUPON_CHARS)
```

---

To be compatible,we can adapt [Ruby on Rails' base58 method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6f0d1ad14b92b9f5906e44740fce8b4f1c7075dc/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/securerandom.rb#L24) for compatibility.

```
ALPHANUMERIC = ("0".."9").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a

def secure_alphanumeric(n, chars: ALPHANUMERIC)
  alphanumeric_size = chars.size

  return SecureRandom.random_bytes(n).unpack("C*").map do |byte|
    idx = byte % 64
    idx = SecureRandom.random_number(alphanumeric_size) if idx >= alphanumeric_size
    chars[idx]
  end.join
end
```

Then use `scan` + `join` to add the dashes.

```
ALPHABET = '234679QWERTYUPADFGHX'.split(//)

puts secure_alphanumeric(16, chars: ALPHABET).scan(/.{4}/).join('-')
```

Comment: Thanks @Schwern! What do you mean, that it's not fully baked in Ruby 3.3. What are the disadvantages? What does not work, as in 3.4? I'm not on Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @wuarmin I've updated the answer with details. Undocumented features and private methods are not guaranteed to work the same from version to version.