# At what scope are Azure event log IDs unique?

Tags: azure-api-management, audit-logging

I have an application that monitors activity logs from multiple different and unrelated Azure platforms using Microsoft’s [Management Activity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference). According to the Common Schema [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#common-schema), event IDs are “Unique identifier[s] of an audit record.” but it does not specify a scope. Are they globally unique across all Azure instances, or is it possible I will have an ID collision between two unrelated instances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs can be assumed to be unique, and the chance of collision is highly unlikely. Refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977648/10417839) that covers this eloquently.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective - a very good point. I already use `INSERT IGNORE` with a unique GUID column when entering new events into the db on account of Microsoft's tendency to resend the same event multiple times, so combined with the size of the GUID space I _should_ never have any issues. Just don't tell my boss : )