# I need to generate uuid for my rails application. What are the options(gems) I have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guid, uuid

I use 
Rails 3.0.20 and 
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)

Please suggest me the best plugin to generate guid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021372/best-way-to-create-unique-token-in-rails

Comment: Virtual, there is no way to flag an incorrect answer and the notion of that is questionable. But I strongly suggest you take a look at @apneadiving's answer. Imho, that is the correct answer and a lot of people will miss it because it's at the bottom of the page.

Comment: **all new Rails versions provide `Digest::UUID`, e.g. `Digest::UUID.uuid_v4`**

Answer (score 320, accepted):

There are plenty of options, I recommend not to add additional dependencies and use `SecureRandom` which is builtin:

```
SecureRandom.uuid #=> "1ca71cd6-08c4-4855-9381-2f41aeffe59c"
```

See other possible formats [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom).

Comment: I would suggest this comment being the correctly checked answer. UUID is a universal format for GUIDs, but anything really goes.

Comment: I would suggest rechecking this as the correct answer based on the fact that it's a built in feature and it generates valid UUIDs for PG.

Comment: SecureRandom#uuid does not appear to be in Ruby 1.8.7.  Looks like it was added in 1.9.3: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/SecureRandom/uuid/class

Comment: ruby 1.8.x is not supposed to be used anymore

Comment: yes of course.  And yet the question specifically referred to 1.8.7.

Comment: its just a require away then

Comment: not sure I follow.  SecureRandom does exist as part of the stdlib in 1.8.7 but it doesn't have the uuid method: see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_352/lib/securerandom.rb

Comment: it available as a gem in your case: https://rubygems.org/gems/rubysl-securerandom

Comment: @apneadiving Oh, whoops. I'd looked at the Rails page, not the plain Ruby page, which I'd what made the difference.

Answer (score 17):

The first thing I would suggest is to please upgrade your ruby and rails versions.

A very good way of generating guids is [SecureRandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), which is a ruby module with easy usage.

```
require 'securerandom'
guid = SecureRandom.hex(10) #or whatever value you want instead of 10
```

Comment: `require 'securerandom'` is no longer necessary if using Rails 3.1 or higher.

Comment: UUID has RFC! This will break any UUID validation (like in PostgreSQL)

Comment: hex SecureRandom is not UUID. The formal definition of the UUID string representation is explained in RFC 4122

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using PostgreSQL and using the uuid column built in, it autogenerates UUID based on type you create the column.

Example in Rails 3 migration

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE some_items (id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1());
SQL
```

Might be a better way to do this in Rails 4.

Comment: I like this approach; could you add more details?

Comment: There's no mention of using PG in the question. Recommending a new database system is not much help...

Answer (score 2):

Please see in detail, how to use securerandom ruby standard library to use UUID with example in rails 3.X and 4.X

create usesguid.rb file in your lib/usesguid.rb and paste below code in that -

```
require 'securerandom'

module ActiveRecord
  module Usesguid #:nodoc:
    def self.append_features(base)
      super
      base.extend(ClassMethods)  
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def usesguid(options = {})
        class_eval do
          self.primary_key = options[:column] if options[:column]
          after_initialize :create_id
          def create_id
            self.id ||= SecureRandom.uuid
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  include ActiveRecord::Usesguid
end
```

add following line in your config/application.rb to load file -

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib/usesguid'
```

Create migration script for UUID function as mentioned below to -

```
class CreateUuidFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "create or replace function uuid() returns uuid as 'uuid-ossp', 'uuid_generate_v1' volatile strict language C;"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "drop function uuid();"
  end
end
```

Here is example for contact migration, how we can use it -

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts, id: false do |t|
      t.column :id, :uuid, null:false 
      t.string :name
      t.string :mobile_no

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Final how  to use into your model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  usesguid

end
```

This will help you to configure UUID for your rails application.

This can be useful for Rails 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 4.0 as well.

Please let me know If you have any issue while using it, so simple!

Other options for Rails4 [here](http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/10/dev-bit-auto-generate-uuid-postgres-rails-4/)

Comment: My reason to use this in Rails 4, Actually I wanted to use earlier version of postgreSQL. If you have not such dependancy then can go for builtin feature.