# How to create a special order_number that is based off the table id column in PostgreSQL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Orders table in a SQL database (PostgreSQL if it matters, and Rails 4.04) and I want the column "number" in the orders table to kind of shadow the id column. In other words I want an automatic sequential field but I want it to be in the form:

```
Order::PRODUCT_NU_PREFIX + ((Order::STARTING_PRODUCT_NO + order.id).to_s)
```

So that if I set

```
PRODUCT_NU_PREFIX = 'PE' and 
STARTING_PRODUCT_NO = '11681'
```

Then the first order I create will have a product number:

```
KB11682 and then 
KB11683
```

SHould I do this purely in PostgreSQL or is there a good way to do it in Rails? Keep in mind I'll need to know what the latest Order.id is when an order comes in because when I save that new record I want that field to get saved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at [`uuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)'s (Universally Unique Identifiers)

These basically allow you to assign a special `id` to a record, giving you an instant reference throughout your app. Such use cases for this include the likes of `order numbers`, `API keys` and `message ID's`

We actually implement what you're asking quite regularly:

```
#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_num

    private
    def set_num
        unless self.num
            loop do
                token =  SecureRandom.hex(10)
                break token unless self.class.exists?(num: token)
            end
        end
    end

end

orders
id | num | other | attrs | created_at | updated_at
```

---

[Rails has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228324/i-need-to-generate-uuid-for-my-rails-application-what-are-the-optionsgems-i-h) a series of built-in [UUID-generators](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom):

```
SecureRandom.uuid #=> "1ca71cd6-08c4-4855-9381-2f41aeffe59c"
SecureRandom.hex(10) # => "52750b30ffbc7de3b362"
SecureRandom.base64(10) # => "EcmTPZwWRAozdA=="
```

Comment: Can it also be used to generate a sequence of `employee_codes` like `RE1000`,`RE1001`,`RE1002`.. etc?

Comment: Hi Pavan - I hope you're doing well - see you a lot on here! This wouldn't be good as an incremental storage system; by nature `uuid` is meant to be completely unique. What you're looking at would be best applied at the DB-level with `auto-increment`

Comment: Having [looked this up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-suffix), it seems you're only able to use `INT` columns for `auto-increment`. I could write a simple algorithm for your `employee_codes` if you like; but it would need more than just `auto-increment I think`!

Comment: Thanks! Right now we are doing like that! Just eager to know whether it work in my case.Anyways Your answer is great.I learned a new one today :)

Comment: No problem - hope it helps you. In terms of your `employee_codes` thing, I would recommend asking a question about it, but in a general sense, you'll probably want to use a `before_create` callback like I've recommended here, with a method to determine the employee number, and then populate the attribute with it

Comment: Hmm,surely will think about asking as a question in SO! Thanks again mate!