# Generating a unique URL with tokens in Rails 4 for an external form response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, token, friendly-id

I have a 'Feedback' model whereby a user should be able to request feedback on his/her job performance. I have written basic actions for creating a new feedback request, and the mailer for sending the request to the provider (person who will respond with feedback).

**I would like advice from the community on implementing the following:**

- Once a new feedback request is created, the email that is sent should contain a link to a form where the provider can input his feedback on the users performance.
- The feedback provider should not be required to log-in or sign-up in any way (i.e. completely external to the application).
- Once submitted, feedback from the provider should be captured in the
  system.

**Now, I have the following ideas to implement it, but am not sure if this is the best way to proceed:**

- Generate a unique token upon the creation of a new feedback request. Something like this: [Best way to create unique token in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021372/best-way-to-create-unique-token-in-rails).
- The token should then be entered into 'feedbacks' table.
- Mailer should then generate variable (e.g. @url) which generates link to another controller (let's say 'external_feedback' and action which does not require log-in (e.g. no before_filter :authenticate_user! from Devise).
- That URL should contain a parameter with the token for the specific feedback request.
- The action should be to update the 'feedback' request and a form generated with simple_form.

The whole thing is similar to responding to a questionnaire or survey (like Survey Monkey).

After some research I believe the Friendly ID gem may be useful here. I was also reading Section 8 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and perhaps I need to implement an authenticity_token in the formal sense. What I am really looking for is:

- Is the above approach the generally correct way to go about doing this?
- If so, any specifics on how you would implement it (with or without Friendly ID)?
- Do you know of any gems that exist for generating such URLs/tokens?

Thank you in advance. I am now including the current state of model and controller details:

```
feedback.rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: feedbacks
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id      :integer
#  p_first_name :string(255)
#  p_last_name  :string(255)
#  p_email      :string(255)
#  goal_id      :integer
#  u_comment    :text
#  p_comment    :text
#  created_at   :datetime
#  updated_at   :datetime
#

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :goal

  has_many :feedback_attributes

  validates_presence_of :p_first_name, :p_last_name, :p_email, :goal_id

end
```

And this is my mailer:

```
class FeedbackMailer < ActionMailer::Base

   def feedback_request(user, feedback)
    @user = user
    @feedback = feedback
    @url  = 'http://thisistheexampleurlforfeedback'
    mail(to: @feedback.p_email, subject: "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name} has requested your feedback", from: @user.email)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a token field to the feedback model with an index and add a callback to populate it on create  e.g.
feedback.rb

```
before_create :add_token
private
def add_token
  begin
    self.token = SecureRandom.hex[0,10].upcase
  end while self.class.exists?(token: token)
end
```

now add a new route for the providers feedback

```
resources :feedbacks do 
  get 'provider'
  put 'provider_update' # you might not need this one, if you are happy to use update
end
```

In your controller make sure they don't get rejected by devise

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:provider, :provider_update]
...
def provider
  @feedback = Feedback.find_by token: params[:token]
end
```

then in the app/views/feedback/provider.html.haml you can use url in simple_form to send it to the correct update location and only provide the input that they should see.

```
f.inputs :p_comment
```

Now update your mailer.

```
@url = provider_feedback_url(@feedback, token: @feedback.token)
```

You could do something similar to this using friendly id but you would still need to create some sort of unique slug and then use Feedback.friendly.find instead. I think you would want to combine it with a token to ensure it's still the provider giving the feedback - so the only benefit would really be hiding the true id/count. I think you should update p_* fields to provider_* so that the next dev knows what's in it - it's not the 90s!

Comment: Great response, thanks David. Worked perfect for me.

Comment: is this token generation logic will maintain unique tokens like primary key? or it duplicates the token? for eg: say it generated randomly a token "123" .so is there any chance that it will generate "123" randomly again?

Comment: @John depending on how much traffic your website gets, this token generation logic could generate a duplicate token as often as once in a quadrillion times. It'd be much safer to do put a unique index on token and do  `begin; self.token = SecureRandom.hex[0,10].upcase; rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique; retry; end`