# Creating urls like :user/:post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I was just wondering how I would make urls theoretically like localhost:3000/:user/post/:post like twitter e.g. https://twitter.com/PigsAndPlans/status/491290440512331776 and how to give the post a unique id of both numbers and letters like vine http://vine.co/v/M2JYAhg3HHY.

Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose you've read about the [Routing system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) that does exactly this?  That and modifying `to_param` (as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732)) should get you what you need.

Comment: @PinnyM The Routing article certainly helped. I had seen it but only skimmed it and missed the bit I needed haha but for the id I was talking more about the actual generating of the number

Comment: That's where `to_param` comes in - see the linked article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your routes file will match the first URL pattern

```
match ":username/post/:post_id", to: "users_posts#index"
```

and give you `params[:username]` and `params[:post_id]` variables in your controller. Think very carefully about putting a variable (:username) as the first part of a route, though. You'll have to make sure your app never needs a URL that will conflict with that pattern. A better approach is the vine URL pattern you give, which has a `/v` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can create url pattern with following code in config/routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

# http://localhost:3000/users/:user_id/posts/:post_id
```

Comment: @whyelse you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021372/best-way-to-create-unique-token-in-rails or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115929/generating-a-unique-url-with-tokens-in-rails-4-for-an-external-form-response to generate unique token