# What is the difference between tr and gsub?

Tags: ruby

I was reading the Ruby documentation and got confused with the difference between `gsub` and `tr`. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I found this question because RuboCop alerted on my use of gsub -- I think the answers below explain the answer well, which is basically what's the difference between gsub and tr.

Answer (score 224):

Use [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr) when you want to replace (translate) single characters.

`tr` matches on *single* characters (not via a regular expression), therefore the characters don't need to occur in the same order in the first string argument. When a character is found, it is replaced with the character that is found at the same index in the second string argument:

```
'abcde'.tr('bda', '123')
#=> "31c2e"

'abcde'.tr('bcd', '123')
#=> "a123e"
```

Use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) when you need to use a regular expression or when you want to replace longer substrings:

```
'abcde'.gsub(/bda/, '123')
#=> "abcde"

'abcde'.gsub(/b.d/, '123')
#=> "a123e"
```

Comment: Bit of context: the name `tr` means "translate", as in "translate characters", which is exactly what it does. It's named after the Unix utility of the same name (which are well known for their obscure and short names).

Answer (score 47):

- `tr` can only replace a single character with a single fixed character (although you can put multiple matches of this sort in a single `tr` call) but is fast.
- `gsub` can match complicated patterns using regex, and replace with a complicated computation result, but is slower than `tr`.

Comment: That right. When both works `tr` is several times faster than `gsub`. Here is a benchmark on how fast `tr` could be than `gsub`.  https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby/blob/master/code/string/gsub-vs-tr.rb

Answer (score 10):

`tr` returns a copy of `str` with the characters in `from_str` replaced by the corresponding characters in `to_str`. If `to_str` is shorter than `from_str`, it is padded with its last character in order to maintain the correspondence. 
http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr

`gsub` returns a copy of `str` with the all occurrences of pattern substituted for the second argument. The pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. `\d` will match a backlash followed by `d`, instead of a digit.
http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub