# How to use gsubstitution with more letters

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I've printed the code, wit ruby

```
string = "hahahah"
pring string.gsub("a","b")
```

How do I add more letter replacements into gsub?

```
string.gsub("a","b")("h","l") and string.gsub("a","b";"h","l")
```

didnt work...

*update I have tried this too but without any success .

```
letters = {
"a" => "l"
"b" => "n"
...
"z" => "f"
}
string = "hahahah"
print string.gsub(\/w\,letters)
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the tr (translate) method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749065/what-is-the-difference-between-tr-and-gsub  gsub substitutes one string with another, tr translates a set of characters into a different set of characters: string.tr("ah","bl")

Comment: This problem is exactly use case of tr.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating. As with most method calls in Ruby, you can simply chain `#gsub` calls together, one after the other:

```
str = 'adfh'
print str.gsub("a","b").gsub("h","l") #=> 'bdfl'
```

What you're doing here is applying the second `#gsub` to the result of the first one.

Of course, that gets a bit long-winded if you do too many of them. So, when you find yourself stringing too many together, you'll want to look for a regex solution. [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) is a great place to tinker with them.

The way to use your hash trick with `#gsub` and a regex expression is to provide a hash for all possible matches. This has the same result as the two `#gsub` calls:

```
print str.gsub(/[ah]/, {'a'=>'b', 'h'=>'l'}) #=> 'bdfl'
```

The regex matches either `a` or `h` (`/[ah]/`), and the hash is saying what to substitute for each of them.

All that said, `str.tr('ah', 'bl')` is the simplest way to solve your problem as specified, as some commenters have mentioned, so long as you are working with single letters. If you need to work with two or more characters per substitution, you'll need to use `#gsub`.

Comment: Good answer, Bob. I had overlooked it when I posted my now-deleted answer, the content of which you had already covered.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks Cary. Perhaps you were in the middle of writing yours when I posted mine. No doubt that happens to you as often as it happens to me!