# Generating token is returning nil in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am trying to generate Token to authenticate rails Api client. I have used `generate_key_method` in mode class.

```
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base

before_create :generate_access_token

validates :access_token, uniqueness: true

def generate_access_token
  begin
    self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
  end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
 end
end
```

[inserts null while creating record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVvMc.png)

Answer (score 1):

`before_create` callbacks happen after validation. In your case, the uniqueness validation is failing and halting the callback chain before the `before_create` callbacks can be triggered. You can set the access token before validating on create:

```
before_validation :generate_access_token, on: :create
```

Please see the page on [active record callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for more information and for the whole ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109098/1143732) answer.

The correct way to achieve what you're doing is to use the following:

```
#app/models/api_key.rb
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :generate_key

  protected

  def generate_key
    self.access_token = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.hex
      break random_token unless ApiKey.exists?(access_token: random_token) #-> this acts in place of the validation
    end
  end

end
```

--

The above is now deprecated, in favour of [ActiveRecord's Secure Token functionality](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/secure_token.rb):

```
#app/models/api_key.rb
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_token :access_token
end

key = ApiKey.new
key.save 
key.access_token # -> "pX27zsMN2ViQKta1bGfLmVJE"
```