# Is there a way to generate a unique integer permalink?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a unique numeric permalink in rails. My problem is that I need to make sure it is unique, has between 5 and 7 numbers and is randomly generated (so not simply counting up). I did look at FriendlyID but I am not sure if this can deliver what I need - the url for my permalink should eventually look like this:

www.kreelu.com/4325677

Is there a build in feature or a gem that can provide this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117584/guids-in-ruby

Comment: Do you require any security on this? 5 digits is not really enough to be secure if you have even a moderate number (e.g. 10) of valid numbers. Could you clarify the purpose?

Comment: I think you can use has_permalink gem. i am not sure your purpose solved but it is helpfull to you. See the url http://haspermalink.org/

Comment: You save the permalinks right? Just use ruby's rand() method with a range excluding the existig permalinks from range

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby

Comment: @neilSlater It doesn't need to be secure since it will only be accessible from time to time (it basically exposes a page temporarily under specific circumstances and takes it offline once the conditions change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
after_validation :set_permalink

def rand_permalink #you can find a better way to exclude loop db-searches
  r = rand.to_s[2..8] # 7-digit random, you can make [2..11] for 10-digits and so on
  while find_by_permalink(r).present?
    r = rand.to_s[2..8]
  end
  r      
end 


def set_permalink
  permalink = rand_permalink unless permalink.presence
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create the unique `permalink` on create, you want to store it in your database and the class is named `Post`:

```
validate :permalink, :uniqueness => true

before_create :create_permalink

private
  def create_permalink
    loop do
      self.permalink = Array(1..7).map{ rand(10).to_s }.join
      return if Posts.where(permalink: permalink).blank?
    end
  end
```