# How can I add an auto generated ID to an existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in my schema that does not have an auto generated ID primary key because I deactivated that option when creating it. Is there a way to put a new column ID that is auto incremented in my table?

Comment: In simplest case you can do hash. Why do you need it to be auto incremented? i.e. Does increment make sense? Possibly [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117584/generating-guids-in-ruby) is helpful.

Comment: This new ID column will be the primary key after I remove the current primary key column. I know I could just edit my migration, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with a new migration file.

Comment: Increment implies that your sequence has a relationship with time, but do you need it? If you only need to identify a table then timeless hash is effective (even more effective when doing some checks bc you can hash on attributes so it contains more information). Also I wonder why do you remove generated ID? It has to be with some reason.

Comment: I don't think it necessarily has to do with time, but since users in my systems can add new resources to the table, the ID column seems like a simple way to identify  rows uniquely, even if the information in some of them is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to Add new migration, also if there is not much more data which is most useful, than rails Also provide functionality to **DOWN** Migration.

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20190204205537
```

'20190204205537' this should be your migration version

it will 'DOWN'  your migration, than you can edit it, i mean remove the **PRIMARY KEY** false. and simply run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I Hope this may help to you.
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I'll try and edit current migrations if other people haven't ran them on their systems

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generate a migration with `primary_key`:

```sh
rails g migration add_id_to_my_tables id:primary_key
```

That will produce a `change` with [add_column](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column):

```rb
def change
  add_column :my_tables, :id, :primary_key
end
```

Comment: Will this make the column auto incremented?

Comment: Yes, Rails' primary_keys are auto incremented by default.