Handle concurrent request in Ruby on Rails application for sensitive code
I have an api that creates wallet transactions, this API is built in rails and we expect that the transaction_id/reference_no will be unique for each transaction per bank since we have many banks and there are so many ways to create wallet transactions in the app we do not have model validation for unique transaction_id.
In APIs, we have a before_action that checks if any wallet entry already exists with the same transaction_id and then we generate an error.
But now we have a case on production in which bank was able to send multiple concurrent request at the same time to create a 2 wallet entry with the same transcation id, I checked the database and found that both records have the same created_at.
I was able to reproduce the same behavior locally by writing a ruby script that send those concurrent request now the issue is that Rails process both requests at the same time and even if we add a rails active record validaton, rails runs the exists query for both of them at the same time and both returns nil so it creates 2 record. The only way to stop this is to add database level uniquess check but have around 15 production database and we might have duplicated records there, since this is a sensitive part of the could I would like to know how others are handling this concurrent requests on rails application
I've tried a few things

add validation
Use Ruby's Mutex
MySQL locking with GET_LOCK

but no luck so far

Do you mean, transaction ids have to be unique across multiple databases?

No, We have the same Rails application running on different servers for each client with each application having the it's own database but the schema is same.
If we add a database uniqueness, we need to first check all databases if we have duplicated records or not. I've checked a few and found a bunch of duplicated old records

That's why I do not want to add uniqueness on transcation_id at the database level.

I probably would add db level uniqueness constraint. I would either use GUIDs as transaction id or have a client-specific part if the transaction id.

but we already have duplicated records with the same transcation_id in the database, this data is quite old and it would be impossible to clean this up at this point. I'm wondering why Rails processes both requests at the same time and by the looks of it, it doesn't look like a ground-breaking problem, there must be a way around it as getting concurrent request is quit common these days

Anything outside of a database level constraint is going to be unreliable at best.  Clean up -- while painful -- allows the only reliable solution. Concurrency is a hard problem.

What you do with your old duplicates is a very different question to how you handle uniqueness going forward. Since we do not know your system at all, we can't really tell you how to handle historic duplicates. GUIDs have been around for quite a while and they are usually guaranteed to be unique for a few million IDs / second (always check implementation notes). For example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117584/generating-guids-in-ruby for Ruby. Using a combination of client id + per client unique transaction id can also work. Otherwise, you are in for a big locking exercise.

Yes I understand that but, it is not about generating a unique ID, I'm looking for a solution to handle the concurrent request in Rails, by any chance, we can identify the concurrent request or somehow we can run the active record validation during the concurrent request would solve it the issue.

@MIbtehajNasar validations will not matter if they are being performed concurrently because both requests will see if the id exists, both will determine it does not and boom duplicates. Unfortunately your options are: a) use validations, with the knowledge that this could happen; b) set database level constraints and determine how to resolve the current issues; or c) change the workflow such that you generate your own unique ids and return them to the submitting party. Personally I am preferential to (c) because it lets them store their own data and lets you control uniqueness.
